# How to use modules in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just created a module **location.rb** inside **/lib** folder with following contents:

```
module Location
  def self.my_zipcode()
    zip_code = "11215"
  end
end
```

And now in my controller i am trying to call "my_zipcode" method:

```
class DirectoryController < ApplicationController
  def search
    require 'location'
    zip_code = Location.my_zipcode()
  end
end
```

But it throws an error:

> undefined method `my_zipcode' for Location:Module

Comment: Works for me (and that's what it should).

Comment: You might have to restart the rails server for it to recognize stuff in the lib directory.

Comment: maaaaan you saved my day :) restarting a server did the trick. Can you post an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: Niklas, FYI `Location::my_zipcode` is the same as `Location.my_zipcode`.

Comment: Just FYI, you don'5 need parentheses after methods with no parameters :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have to restart the rails server for it to recognize stuff in the lib directory.

Comment: do you know if i have to restart a server every time i update a module code?

Comment: that's what I usually have to do, I'm not sure how to get around it

Comment: I usually add an app/modules folder to put them in while developing. That way they get reloaded on every request.

Comment: @BradleyPriest: interesting, I'll have to try that

Answer (score 13):

You can also add the following to your config/application.rb

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

And it should autoload your module without having to restart rails.

Comment: Thanks outside2344, very nice solution :)